# Catch KeyCode in AjaxBehaviorEvent of JSF 2

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a JSF ajax keyup event linked to an event listner in a backing bean.

The code in the JSF file is like below.

```
<h:inputText id="txtDescription" value="#{institutionController.current.description}" disabled="#{institutionController.modifyControlDisable}" >
    <f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{institutionController.changeDetailsEvent}" />
</h:inputText>
```

The code in the backing bean is like below.

```
public void changeDetailsEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
}
```

I want to achieve different logic depending on the key presses, like shown is pseudocode below.

```
public void changeDetailsEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    If (event.key = Key.enter) {
        do something;
    } else if (event.key = Key.Escape) {
        so something else;
    } else {
        do nothing;
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me how this is done in the backing bean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `AjaxBehaviorEvent` doesn't contain any information about the JavaScript `event` object. You need to pass the desired information along yourself. This can be achieved by a hidden input field whose value is to be prefilled by JavaScript. For example,

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" onkeyup="document.getElementById('#{keyCode.clientId}').value=event.keyCode">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this keyCode" listener="#{bean.listener}" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputHidden id="keyCode" binding="#{keyCode}" value="#{bean.keyCode}" />
```

*(please note that the `id` of the hidden field is included in `execute` so that it get submitted along on the ajax request, please also note that the `binding` is used to be able to dynamically obtain the generated client ID in `document.getElementById()` in order to set the key code value, you could alternatively also hardcode the client ID if it's fixed)*

with

```
private String input;
private int keyCode;

public void listener() {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case 13:
            // Enter key was pressed.
            break;
        case 27:
            // Escape key was pressed.
            break;
        default:
            // Other key was pressed.
            break;
    }
}
```

You can find an overview of all valid `keyCode` values in the [Mozilla DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event/UIEvent/KeyEvent).

Comment: can we do this in javascript.
For example I wanted to show alert "you pressed the key - 'A' "

Comment: @BalusC: Maybe this is something to propose for JSF 2.3? I hear more and more people about things like this. [PrimeFaces added this in several components to already](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/93100401e15ea70c92ae3014e9ad7673c3e4129b)