# Fire f:ajax only on specific keys

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, delay, jsf-2.2

I use `f:ajax` inside `h:inputText` to call on a backing bean method that executes a search based on the input, with a delay:

```
<h:inputText
    ...>
    <f:ajax 
        delay="500" 
        event="keyup"
        listener="#{cc.attrs.completeMethod}"
        onevent="function(data){mx.util.onComplete(data, mx.ezOverlay.handle)}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Now I'd like to somehow NOT send requests for every key - specifically not arrow keys, which I use to navigate a drop down list with the results.

I know how to do this through binding a `jQuery` event listener to the input, manually check which key was used and having a timer on concert with `PrimeFaces RemoteCommand` to handle delay and call to method.

My question is if there's a way to avoid sending ajax request for certain keys, e.g. SHIFT, CTRL and ARROW keys; when using `f:ajax`. Or maybe there's a much better way to handle delays (with the goal of not sending every keystroke to the backing bean -> not search database for every keystroke).

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, yet still pointing to the existing answer to this question (link below):

[Catch KeyCode in AjaxBehaviorEvent of JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652225/catch-keycode-in-ajaxbehaviorevent-of-jsf-2)

Hope this helps.