# Call java method in JSF/xhtml by keyPress and update form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I got school project to code game in JSF but I struggle o lot with keyboard.

I want to call method `moveCubeUp()`  from cubefield to move UP if user press keyboard UP and then update form and do this to all 4 directions.

 I tried javascripts, jQuery, primefaces hotkey

This is in my xhtml:

```
                <div class="game">
                    <h:form id="form">
                        <g:cuberoll value="#{cubefield}"/>

                        Cube X: <h:outputLabel value="#{cubefield.getCubeX()}"/>
                        Cube Y: <h:outputLabel value="#{cubefield.getCubeY()}"/>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
```

and cubefield:

```
@Named("cubefield")
@SessionScoped
public class Field implements Serializable{
public Field() {
   ... constructor
}

public void moveCubeRight(){
        ... do stuff
}
```

Comment: Please note that Javascript and Java are very different. Please remove the Javascript tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to trigger it with ajax.
It should look like this :

```
    `<f:ajax event="onkeypress" execute="keyCode" listener="#{bean.listener}" />`
```

Then you can get the key in an hidden input.

```
  `<h:inputHidden id="keyCode" binding="#{keyCode}" value="#{bean.keyCode}" />`
```

This topic is related to what you are asking :
[Catch KeyCode in AjaxBehaviorEvent of JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652225/catch-keycode-in-ajaxbehaviorevent-of-jsf-2)

Comment: still not working, but at least I know now where to start